# register new user with role autor not user (codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter

When a new user wants to register to my blog automatically they be just a user, I must login to admin panel and change it from user to author.

I want any user who wants to register to be an author automatically without need to change it from the admin panel.

**table** : *users* , **column** : *role* , **value** : i want it to be always : *author* not *user* .

**Auth model :**

```
    //register
public function register()
{
    $data = $this->auth_model->input_values();
    //secure password
    $data['password'] = $this->bcrypt->hash_password($data['password']);
    $data['slug'] = $this->generate_uniqe_slug($data["username"]);
    $data['token'] = generate_unique_id();
    $data['last_seen'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $data["created_at"] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    if ($this->db->insert('users', $data)) {
        $id = $this->db->insert_id();
        $user = $this->get_user($id);
        //set user data
        $user_data = array(
            'inf_ses_id' => $user->id,
            'inf_ses_username' => $user->username,
            'inf_ses_email' => $user->email,
            'inf_ses_role' => $user->role,
            'inf_ses_logged_in' => true,
            'inf_ses_app_key' => $this->config->item('app_key'),
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

//add user
public function add_user()
{
    $this->load->library('bcrypt');
    $data = $this->auth_model->input_values();
    $data['role'] = $this->input->post('role', true);
    $data['token'] = generate_unique_id();
    //secure password
    $data['password'] = $this->bcrypt->hash_password($data['password']);
    $data['slug'] = $this->generate_uniqe_slug($data["username"]);
    $data["created_at"] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    return $this->db->insert('users', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all new users to be authors, simply set `$data['role'] = "author";`. You can then remove that role input since, it will not be necessary.

Comment: Where do you set the default value for role? It is either in your code or the database field has a default. can you trace the function add_user?